# Parallelism Sources / material / papers / books / blogs?

Tags: design-patterns, parallel-processing, transactional

I want to start learning about parallelism. Appropriately,

1. Approaches to write programs which attain parallelism
2. Issues in writing code for Multi-core Architecture
3. Design Patterns in parallelism
4. Program optimizations techniques for multi-core architectures
5. also something about transactional memory [While searching for parallelism , i came across this term].

I am collecting resources to do the same. Here is some stuff that I have found:

http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/patterns-ace.html
[Patterns for Parallel Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321228111)

Just requesting to share your resources.

Comment: Are you mostly interested in shared memory (SMP/NUMA) programming or would also want to learn about distributed memory (message passing/PGAS) programming? Both are quite diverse in terms of what and how, despite the overlap.

Comment: I am kind of confused with this why to mix parallelism with distributed programming or shared memory. Because after roaming over google, I found that in parallelism you have to optimize code for single CPU{may be multicore}..nothing like shared or distributed

Comment: Single-core performance is usually achieved through **vectorisation** and not through **parallelism**. Multicore programming _is_ shared memory parallel programming - each core can access all the system memory and parallel execution is achieved by multiple cooperating threads, each running on different core.

Comment: It would be better if you provide sources for the both.

Comment: Any resources for beginner to step into this world!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by first learning about how different parallel architectures work. There are plenty of freely available and quality materials on the Internet.

### Tutorials and course materials

**Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory** (LLNL) provides a nice set of [HPC tutorials](https://computing.llnl.gov/?set=training&page=index).

**Edinburgh Parallel Computing Centre** (EPCC) also provides for free large amount of [course training materials](http://www.epcc.ed.ac.uk/library/training/).

I leave this answer as a community wiki so anyone can modify it and add other sources.